# .NET MAUI TableView collapses when Entry control receives focus

Tags: maui

I have a `TableView` in which I render form controls for data editing.

However, as soon as the `Entry` control receives focus, the `ViewCell` seemingly collapses, leaving only the section title and separator borders visible:

```
    <TableView Intent="Data">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection Title="Details">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.5*,0.5*">
                        <Label Text="Manufacturer" />
                        <Entry Text="{Binding Manufacturer}" Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>
```

Initial state:

[image: Before]

After tapping the `Entry` element:

[image: After]

I've tried setting a specific height for the `Grid` and the `Entry` control, but I get the same result regardless.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in .NET MAUI: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10322

I ran into this a while ago and reported it. For now, I have created my own table using a Grid.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope this gets fixed soon, but the team seems to be swamped with issues at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can change The TableView HeightRequest property to a large number such as 700.
This is a **temporary workaround** until the bug is fixed.

```
<TableView HeightRequest="700">
    <TableRoot>
        <TableSection>
            <!-- Your code goes here -->
        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

But, in most scenarios, you don't know what the Height is so you could set it dynamically in your code behind.

Page constructor:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // if you want your table height to fit half of the page
        Table.HeightRequest = this.Height / 2; 

        // Rest of logic...

    }
```

Xaml:

```
    <TableView x:Name="Table">
            <TableRoot>
                <TableSection>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="Example"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </TableSection>
            </TableRoot>
        </TableView>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's clear to me, bot.